# WPF Slider run time error

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have 2 sliders in my program. My second slider is never allowed to be less than my first slider, so if someone were to try to slide the second slider down past the first one, the first one would always equal the second one.

I'm coding this in C#, and I don't understand why this code does not work:

```
//SLIDER 1
        private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            if (slider2.Value <= slider1.Value)
                slider1.Value = slider2.Value;
        }
```

XAML - My second slider that the compiler says is `null` at runtime:

```
<Slider Height="22" Margin="128,45,130,0" Name="slider2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Maximum="160" Minimum="1" TickFrequency="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Value="50" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" ValueChanged="slider2_ValueChanged" />
```

The compiler says `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code`, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. What do I need to do to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: Well obviously either `slider1` or `slider2` is `null` during the execution.

Comment: `slider1` is set at 30 and `slider2` is set at 50. How is one of them `null`?

Comment: Well, where is your `StackTrace`? Did you set the CLR exceptions to thrown in `Debug > Exceptions` dialog? It will cause the program to stop at the point, where the `Exception` is raised.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error? Like DHN said, do you have a stack trace? Did you debug it to see if they were both non-null?

Comment: Maybe you should run this check only when your `Window` `IsLoaded`

Comment: When I debug `slider1` is 10 and `slider2` is `null`, which I don't understand because I've explicitly set the value to 50, it's right there in my code (I've added the XAML above).

Comment: @Ericafterdark Well since `ValueChanged` is invoked every time, the value is changed and `slider1` seems to be initialized before `slider2`, which is also a value change...well you get the rest on your own, right?

Comment: @DHN I feel like I get it, but how do I make sure that all of my sliders are initialized correctly?

Comment: So you need to check NULL by if-condition or try-catch block for avoiding NullReferenceException. In this case, if-condition seems like effective more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come on, this is an easy one. Basics of programming... O_o

Simply check both controls for `null` before using them.

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (slider1 == null || slider2 == null)
        return;

    if (slider2.Value <= slider1.Value)
        slider1.Value = slider2.Value;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this compiles, but it still doesn't solve my problem. When I slide the second slider down past the first one the first one does not move with it like it should.

Comment: Well since `slider2` is attached to `slider5_ValueChanged(...)`, `slider1_ValueChanged(...)` is not called, when using `slider2`. Additionally, I'm not sure, that the call back is called, since you haven't dropped the slider. Maybe, you have to reconsider your approach. But this was not part of your problem, you've pointed out in your question.

Comment: What is the event handler attached to 'slider2.ValueChanged'? You should have similar code there. Or just attach the same handler. A bit messy if you ask me

Comment: @DHN I caught that, `slider2` is now attached to `slider2_ValueChanged()`. I'll accept your answer because you fixed my problem, but my solution is not functioning correctly.

Comment: @Ericafterdark Well you could open another question. Then I can write you something about `DataBinding` a.s.o. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this problem because when your page initialized and your XAML control started to render then your `slider1_ValueChanged` is being called because you are setting its value to `30`, but your `slider2` is still not initialized.
 That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: This is a much correct answer, the reason is simple setting `Value` property from XAML.